# CSS Import rule does not work on apache subfolder

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix, apache-config

I am creating a Laravel app with laravel-mix.

### The problem

I did import font-awesome in my *resources/css/app.css* file with the following command.

```css
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/regular';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/solid';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/brands';
```

Everything is working fine on my docker, but when i deployed on a LAMP server the fontawesome's fonts start to return a 404 error when the page was loading.

On the server i have the following Apache VirtualHost configuration

```
Alias /assticket /var/www/html/assticket/public
<Directory /var/www/html/assticket>
AllowOverride All
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all

    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
</Directory>
```

I checked and the reason is because the page is resolving the following url:

- https://<host>/fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-solid-900.ttf?e615bbcb258550973c165dfc0d871c96

instead of:

- https://<host>/**assticket**/fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-solid-900.ttf?e615bbcb258550973c165dfc0d871c96

How can i redirect the **@import** rule to this new path?

### What i tryied so far:

#### Use the HTML base tag:

I added this line in the blade template:

```html
<base href="{{ config('app.url') }}" />
```

#### Tryed to change laravel-mix config

i added in the *webpack.mix.js* the following code:

```js
const path = require('path');

mix.webpackConfig({
    output: {
        publicPath: '/assticket/'
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve('resources/js')
        }
    }
});

...
```

Both attemps didn't change anything. After each attempt i cleaned every cache possible in laravel with the following command.

```bash
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan view:clear
php artisan view:cache
```

### Additional Info

#### Laravel version

My laravel version is 8.83

#### webpack.mix.js file

This is my **webpack.mix.js** file, in case it is needed:

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/const.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/ticketform.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/dashboard.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/chat.js', 'public/js')
    .css('resources/css/ticketform.css', 'public/css')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', []);
```

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching i found the solution. I post this as an answer if someone will need it in the future.

### Basic solution

I did resolve by setting up the resource root in the `webpack.mix.js` file with my apache subfolder.

```js
mix.setResourceRoot("/assticket/");
```

### Prettier solution

To make it prettier i did add a new entry in the `.env` file

```
WEBSERVER_SUBFOLDER=/assticket/
```

and changed the `webpack.mix.js` file like below:

```js
require('dotenv').config();
mix.setResourceRoot(process.env.WEBSERVER_SUBFOLDER);
```